# Rearranging blocks of digits

Tags: c, recursion, math

I encountered a hard question I don't know the answer to: "Rearrange the digits from an integer in blocks of two with a recursive function" here's an example:

*Input: 123456*

```
unsigned long pairinvPrint(unsigned long number) {
    printf("%d", number % 100);

    if ((number / 100) <= 99) {
        printf("%d", number / 100);
    }
    else {
        pairinv(number / 100);
    }
}
```

*Output: 563412*
More I/O Examples: 42 -> 42; 1234 -> 3412

However, the set circumstances to do this are hard (no loops, arrays, pointers, global- or static variables, no libraries) and it should not print the solution directly, rather return it upon a call like this:

```
printf("Rearrange int (%lu) = %lu", input, pairinvert(input));
```

Luckily there's one circumstance to make it easier, the number of the input digits is always even.

Now I experimented for a while, but cant come up with a working solution, except the invalid one using `printf`.

Does anyone have some inspiration for me or idea how to tackle this?

Comment: What if number of digits is odd? For example, 12345. What should be the output?

Comment: For simplicity, this is never the case.

Comment: Recursive function should have at least two parts: say, termination condition and subtasking condition. Since it's also required not to print the partial solution from inside the function, it also requires the partial solution storing functionality. All three are pretty obvious in this problem. The only thing is the case of uneven number of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll bite :-)

```
unsigned long p(unsigned long p1, unsigned long p2) {
    // no loops, no arrays, no pointers, no global, no static, no variables, no libraries
    if (p1 < 100) return p2*100 + p1;
    return p(p1/100, p2*100 + p1%100);
}

unsigned long pairinvert(unsigned long n) {
    // no loops, no arrays, no pointers, no global, no static, no variables, no libraries
    if (n < 100) return n;
    return p(n/100, n%100);
}

// need <stdio.h> for printf()
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned long input;
    input = 123456;
    printf("Rearrange int (%lu) = %lu\n", input, pairinvert(input));
    input = 42;
    printf("Rearrange int (%lu) = %lu\n", input, pairinvert(input));
    input = 1234;
    printf("Rearrange int (%lu) = %lu\n", input, pairinvert(input));
}
```

Comment: I did not think of the possibility of using two functions, this is gorgeous! Thanks for your time and answer :) 
The internet is an awesome place for learning things thanks to people like you ^^

Comment: Glad you didn't catch my "cheat" -- the function argument `p2` (or `p1`) is a variable in disguise :)

Comment: If you're allowed to call my function `p()` directly, you can delete `pairinvert()` and call with `printf("%lu\n", p(input, 0));` -- still uses variable in 'disguise'

Answer (score 0):

Following program should work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void rearrange(int n, int *output) {
    int lsd = 0, slsd = 0;

    if(n == 0)
      return;
    if(n > 0) {
        lsd = n%10;
    }
    if (n > 9) {
        slsd = (n%100)/10;
    }

    *output = 100*(*output) + 10*slsd + lsd;

    n = n/100;

    rearrange(n, output);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    int output = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);
    rearrange(n, &output);
    printf("%d\n", output);

    return 0;
}
```

It is simple to understand, so I am not writing any comments.

Note that it is tail recursive so with O2 optimization it can recurse infinitely.

Comment: If you find that this answer is correct please upvote and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
unsigned long pairinv(unsigned long number, unsigned long result) {

    unsigned long n = number % 100;   // Gets the two digit number
    if (n == 0) return result;        // If it's zero returns the result

    result = result * 100 + n;        // Else multiplies the result by 100, adds n
    return pairinv(number / 100, result); // and continues by recursion
}

int main() {
    unsigned long  r= 0;
    printf("%lu\n", pairinv(123456, r)); //==> 563412
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering, although its very readable and looks like its technically working, this solution still uses pointers to store states, which where not allowed. Little thing I noticed: you use an integer placeholder (%d) for print, but the function returns a unsigned long (%ld) value, and it does not work for more than 6 digits, idk why

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice that, but it's fixed now.

Comment: whoops, just checked in to see if new responses have been posted and noticed that I actually wrote the wrong one, its %lu for long unsigned ^^