# Struggling with PairInverse problem in c using recursion

Tags: c

I have three solutions so far but I have to do it without static and without using any function from the library like log, any global or [] also no pointers. I am just out of ideas right now. I don't want solution but just an idea in the right direction as what am I missing. It would be really helpful.

```
long reverse(long);
 
int main()
{
   long n, r;
   printf("Enter any number: ");
   scanf("%ld", &n);
 
   r = reverse(n);
 
   printf("%ld\n", r);
 
   return 0;
}

long reverse(long n) {
   
   
   static long r = 0;
   
   if (n == 0)
      return 0;
   
   r = r * 100;
   r = r + n % 100;
   reverse(n/100);
   return r;
}
```

2nd solution

```
#include<stdio.h>


long fun(long num);

long main(){
   long n,number;
   printf("Enter any number: ");
   scanf("%ld", &n);
   number=fun(n);
   printf("\nAfter reverse the number is :%ld",number);
   return 0;
}

long fun(long num)
{
    
    long digit = (long) log10(num);
    
    
    if(num == 0)
        return 0;
    
    return ((num%100 * pow(10, digit-1)) + fun(num/100));
}
```

Comment: Colleagues? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64836465/rearranging-blocks-of-digits

Comment: Oh yes great sorry I just totally ignored this question before, thank you so much. Have a great day ahead.